# Reports: Differences in File Systems and Databases between 1.9.2.4 and 1.9.3.1

Tags: magento1.9.3.1

If anyone is interested in finding out what are the changes between Magento CE 1.9.2.4 and 1.9.3.1 download the following archives:

- **Folder Comparison Report**:
  http://www.megafileupload.com/89dx/FolderComparisonReport.zip
- **Database Comparison Report**:
  http://www.megafileupload.com/89dm/DatabaseComparisonReport.zip

There are two html files with very nice visual results.